# update item in a list which is in a map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Say I have a structure like this:

```
Map({
  isFetching: false,
  page: 1,
  endOfResults: false,
  results: List()
})
```

How can I update an item in this list.

Say my list is like:

```
Map({
  isFetching: false,
  page: 1,
  endOfResults: false,
  results: List(fromJS([
    {id: 1, scored: 0, conceded: 1},
    {id: 2, scored: 2, conceded: 1},
    {id: 3, scored: 2, conceded: 1},
  ]))
})
```

How could I update the nested list item with an id of 2 to be:

```
{id: 2, scored:3, conceded: 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `updateIn` method:

```js
// Sample data
var data = Immutable.Map({
  isFetching: false,
  page: 1,
  endOfResults: false,
  results: Immutable.fromJS([
    {id: 1, scored: 0, conceded: 1},
    {id: 2, scored: 2, conceded: 1},
    {id: 3, scored: 2, conceded: 1},
  ])
});

// Get modified result
data = data.updateIn(['results',1],x => Immutable.fromJS({id:2, scored:3, conceded:2}));

// Show result                         
console.log(data.toJS());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```